# iphone - UIImageView class shadow

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImageView based class.

At the start of this class, I have this.

```
  if ([super initWithFrame:frame] == nil) {
        return nil;
    }


    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3,3);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;

    // bla bla
```

Despite the shadow being declared there, all objects created with this class using initWithFrame, don't show any shadow.

am I missing something?

thanks

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... thanks! your question made me think about it and the problem was the maskToBounds = YES... apparently the shadow will vanish is this is on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out based on the commend of vodkhang.

The problem is

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I suppose the mask clips the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a CALayer under the image with a shadow. The image with a masksToBounds of YES and the shadow layer NO.